# ¿Por que no funciona mi primer cin.getline();?

Tags: c++

Tengo la duda ya que en mi código el primer `cin.getline();` no funciona, se lo salta, pero los demás si función.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <new>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

struct Data {
    string ClientNo;
    string Name;
    string LastName1;
    string LastName2;
    string Street;
    int StreetAd;
    int ApartmentNo;
    string ZipCode;
    string FederalEntity;
    string Muni;
    string PhoneNo;
    string OCP;
    char Email[50];
    double ToPay;
    double debt;
};
int main()
{
    system("COLOR 3F");
    Data* DynArray;
    DynArray = new (nothrow) Data[50];
    int a, b=0;
    string d;
    bool an;
    char q[20],a0[20],a1[20],a2[20],a3[20],a4[20],a5[50],r;
   Muni m1;
    cout << "***Alta de Clientes***" << endl << endl << endl << endl;
    do
                {
    cout<<"******Bienvenido al menu******"<<endl;
    cout<<"Opcion 1: agregar cliente"<<endl;
    cout<<"Opcion 2: Mostrar Clientes del alma"<<endl;
        cin >> a;
        switch (a)
        {
        case 1:
           do
              {*/
                cout<<endl<<"***Solo numeros***";
                cout <<endl<< "Numero de Cliente: ";
                cin >> DynArray[b].ClientNo;
                cout << endl << "Nombre de Cliente: ";
                cin.getline(a0,10);
                string str0(a0);
                cout<<str0<<" "<<a0;
                DynArray[b].Name=str0;
                cout << endl << "Apellido Paterno: ";
                cin.getline(a1,20);
                string str1(a1);
                DynArray[b].LastName1=str1;
                cout << endl << "Apellido Materno: ";
                cin.getline(a2,20);
                string str2(a2);
                DynArray[b].LastName2=str2;
                cout << endl << "Calle: ";
                cin.getline(a3,20);
                string str3(a3);
                DynArray[b].Street=str3;
                cout << endl << "Numero Exterior: ";
                cin >> DynArray[b].StreetAd;
                cout << endl << "Numero Interior: ";
                cin >> DynArray[b].ApartmentNo;
                cout << endl << "Codigo Postal: ";
                cin >> DynArray[b].ZipCode;
                for(a;an==false;a+0){
                cout<<"***SOLO D.F., Estado de Mexico, e Hidalgo";
                cout << endl << "Entidad Federativa: ";
                cin.getline(a4,20);
                string str4(a4);
                DynArray[b].FederalEntity=str4;
                }}
```

El `for` está así por que con un `while`, o un do while jamas me cerraba el bucle

Comment: Explica que error presenta. Mira esta guía _[mcve]_.

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> DynArray[b].ClientNo;
// ...
cin.getline(a0,10);
```

El *problema*, por llamarlo de alguna forma, surge porque la lectura anterior está leyendo un entero... y esta lectura no elimina el salto de línea final... así, cuando llamas a `getline` éste se encuentra un salto de línea como primer carácter y ahí termina de leer.

Para evitar este problema puedes, simplemente, descartar el primer caracter del buffer:

```
cin >> DynArray[b].ClientNo;
cin.ignore();
// ...
cin.getline(a0,10);
```